# Facebook API - Android:How to post in Facebook wall using Facebook API?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-apps, facebook-wall

I am completely new to Facebook API, got it set up in my project and running but I have absolutely zero clue how to post on the wall to the Facebook account?

I read about Open Graph API but that seems to be only for browsers?

What I need for that I don't have any clue.

I heard about Facebook SDK but don't know how to use that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to post message on facebook wall using Facebook android SDK integrate android app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4883063/how-to-post-message-on-facebook-wall-using-facebook-android-sdk-integrate-androi)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994003/facebook-native-login-using-simple-java-class-in-android

Comment: But my ques is that, Is there any need to use any build library resources? if yes then what is that resources?

Comment: facebook developer section will help you in this regard https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/

Comment: Yes I already had done this. But is there need to approved the specific API by Facebook team to use it in Android?

Comment: yes,you need to allow permissions in your facebook app for specific api's

Comment: yup thanks. How much time normally they takes for permissons? @Kamlesh Arya

Comment: its you that gonna set permissions..facebook will set permissions at the same time without any time limit..but i think your app from sandbox to live mode required some amount of time.probably 1,2hrs.not sure though

Comment: @kamlesh Arya yes but i had already sent my APP to the Facebook developers from 2 days but I hadn't got the reply from them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47650/discussion-between-nirav-dabhi-and-kamlesh-arya)

Answer (score 2):

Yes You will need

socialauth-4.4.rar

or

socialauth-android-3.1.rar

To use facebook and any other API. First you need to create API if need.